# rsync batch mode against unsynchronized targets

Tags: rsync

I'd like to try rsync in batch mode against a list of target hosts. The assumption is that all target hosts are at state X. I'd go and create the batch file for rsync against a reference host in that list and apply it to the remaining hosts. Big question is: What will happen if one of these remaining hosts is NOT at the same state as the reference host (Which may have happened because it was out of the loop the last time i synchronized all hosts). Will rsync tell me that something wrong happened? Or will it happily apply the batch file, producing garbage on the unsynchronised host? Any experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **man rsync**

> The  read-batch  option expects the
>   destination tree that it is updating
>   to be identical to the destination
>   tree that was used to create the batch
>   update fileset.  When a differ-
>   ence between the destination trees is
>   encountered the update might be
>   discarded with a warning (if the file
>   appears to be up-to-date already) or
>   the file-update may be  attempted
>   and then, if the file fails to verify,
>   the update discarded with an error. 
>   This means that it should be safe to
>   re-run a read-batch operation if the
>   command got interrupted.  If    you
>   wish to force the batched-update to
>   always be attempted regardless of the
>   file's size and date, use the -I
>   option (when reading the batch).  If
>   an error occurs, the  destina-    tion
>   tree will probably be in a partially
>   updated state. In that case, rsync can
>   be used in its regular (non-batch)
>   mode of operation to fix up the
>   destination tree.

Comment: well you should probably downvote the question and rtfm me. thanks for the hint!